# Are failed tasks resubmitted in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Are failed tasks automatically resubmitted in Apache Spark to the same or another executor?

Comment: Failed tasks in spark are recomputed, or if you have check pointed them recomputed from the checkpoint, the [paper](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2012/nsdi_spark.pdf) goes into more detail

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe failed tasks are resubmitted because I have seen the same failed task submitted multiple times  on the Web UI. However, if the same task fails multiple times, the full job fail:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 120 in stage 91.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 120.3 in stage 91.0
```

Answer (score 25):

Yes, but there is a parameter set for the max number of failures

```
spark.task.maxFailures  4   Number of individual task failures before giving up on the job. Should be greater than or equal to 1. Number of allowed retries = this value - 1.
```