# What should I do if an executor node suddenly dies in spark-streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am using version 1.6 of spark streaming.

A few days ago, my spark streaming app(context) suddenly shutdown. Looking at the log, one of the executors seems to be shutdown. (The equipment was actually turned off.)

What should I do in case this happens?
(Note that the dynamic allocation option is not available.)

If an executor is shut down, I want the job to be assigned to another executor by itself. My app is runnung under yarn client mode.

```
## log example, at the time of shutdown.

WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from xxxx-hostname/12.34.56.789:12345
ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 2 requests outstanding when connection from xxxx-hostname/12.34.56.789:12345 is closed
ERROR ContextCleaner: Error cleaning broadcast 1123293
WARN BlockManagerMaster: Failed to remove RDD 262104
...
ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 5940957964172608257 to xxxx-hostname/12.34.56.789:12345: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
...
WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to get executor loss reason for executor id 5 at RPC address xxxx-hostname:12345, but got no response. Marking as slave lost. org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
```

Comment: It should automatically reschedule a new task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260006/are-failed-tasks-resubmitted-in-apache-spark

Answer (score 0):

you are running out of hdfs file system space(data node space).